# SQL Server For XML Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

My table structure is as follows:

```
   date             Id        Value
   --------------------------------
   01/01/2005    50000        5              
   01/01/2006    50000        6   
   01/01/2007    50000        7   
   01/01/2005    50001        8   
   01/01/2006    50001        9   
   01/01/2007    50001        10
```

I would like to output the xml using `for xml` in SQL Server in the following format:

```
<Date date = "01/01/2005"> <Id dealId=50000" value="5"/> <Id dealId=50001" value="8"/> </Date> <Date date = "01/01/2006"> <Id dealId=50000" value="6"/> <Id dealId=50001" value="9"/> </Date>
```

---

It would be of great help if someone can help me out with the query in SQL Server. I have tried couple of them myself but I am not getting the exact output.

Comment: You should show an attempt you made, this evidences that you have tried something and a better answer can be given explaining where the code is wrong which helps in peoples learnings.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- using your provided values:
DECLARE @table TABLE ([date] DATE, id INT, value INT);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('01/01/2005',50000,5);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('01/01/2006',50000,6);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('01/01/2007',50000,7);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('01/01/2005',50001,8);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('01/01/2006',50001,9);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('01/01/2007',50001,10);

-- XML Query
-- the outer query groups by date, ensuring each date only shows up once
SELECT 
    [date] AS '@date',
    (
        -- The inner query selects all Ids for each date found in the outer query
        SELECT  id as '@dealId',
                value as '@value'
        FROM @Table B
        WHERE B.date=A.date -- join on date from outer query
        FOR XML PATH ('Id'), TYPE
    )
FROM @Table A
GROUP BY date
FOR XML PATH ('Date');

-- Produces:    
<Date date="2005-01-01">
    <Id dealId="50000" value="5"/>
    <Id dealId="50001" value="8"/>
</Date>
<Date date="2006-01-01">
    <Id dealId="50000" value="6"/>
    <Id dealId="50001" value="9"/>
</Date>
<Date date="2007-01-01">
    <Id dealId="50000" value="7"/>
    <Id dealId="50001" value="10"/>
</Date>
```

Comment: If you feel this answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if I need such a simple xml transformation, I'm using [`for xml raw`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175140.aspx):

```
select
    t1.[date],
    (
        select
            t2.[Id] as dealId, t2.[Value]
        from Table1 as t2
        where t2.[date] = t1.[date]
        for xml raw('Id'), type
    )
from Table1 as t1
group by t1.[date]
for xml raw('Date')

----------------------
<Date date="2005-01-01">
    <Id dealId="50000" Value="5"/>
    <Id dealId="50001" Value="8"/>
</Date>
<Date date="2006-01-01">
    <Id dealId="50000" Value="6"/>
    <Id dealId="50001" Value="9"/>
</Date>
<Date date="2007-01-01">
    <Id dealId="50000" Value="7"/>
    <Id dealId="50001" Value="10"/>
</Date>
```

Try it yourself in the **<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3734e/1)</kbd>**

Some notes:

- You don't have to use **`@` in column names**, because `for xml raw` is attribute-centric by default.
- **Subquery** here is necessary, because you want nested xml and for now it's the only way to get it.
- You also have to use `type` modifier in the subquery to get inner data as xml.